# nginx rewrite всех изображений с папки /upload

Tags: nginx

нужна помощь в составлении rewtite или location для nginx для редиректа всех изображений с папки upload на другой домен.

А именно example.com/upload/folder/somefolder/onemorefolder/name.(png|jp?g)

на images.example.com/folder/somefolder/onemorefolder/name.(png|jp?g)

То есть вырезаем /upload/ и переадресовываем на images.example.com

Answer (score 0):

```
location /upload/ {
    rewrite ^/upload/(.+?).(png|jp?g)$ https://images.example.com/$1.$2 permanent;
    root /path/to/storage;
}
```

Comment: я не проверял, надеюсь, общий смысл понятен

Comment: Увы, не редиректит:(